# Как объединить два словаря в один таким образом, чтобы связывались ссылки

Tags: python, словари, ссылки

Допустим есть следующие словари:

```
    dict1 = dict()
    dict2 = dict()
    dict1["поле"] = 1
    dict2["кукуруза"] = 2
    dictunion = dict()
```

Как в dictunion записать dict1 и dict2, т.е. привести к виду
{
"поле": 1
"кукуруза": 2
}
, чтобы после изменения значений dict1 и dict2, допустим "поле": 10, а "кукуруза": 20
при выводе dictunion получилось следующее:
{
"поле": 10
"кукуруза": 20
}

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = {"key1": "value1 from x", "key2": "value2 from x"}
>>> y = {"key2": "value2 from y", "key3": "value3 from y"}
# объединение словаря `x` с `y`
>>> {**x, **y}
# {'key1': 'value1 from x', 'key2': 'value2 from y', 'key3': 'value3 from y'}
# объединение словаря `y` с `x`
>>> {**y, **x}
# {'key2': 'value2 from x', 'key3': 'value3 from y', 'key1': 'value1 from x'}

# Новое в Python 3.9
>>> x | y
# {'key1': 'value1 from x', 'key2': 'value2 from y', 'key3': 'value3 from y'}
>>> y | x
# {'key2': 'value2 from x', 'key3': 'value3 from y', 'key1': 'value1 from x'}
```

Comment: Дак мне нужно в новый словарь записать 2 словаря

Comment: ну и чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что в данном случае просто перезаписываются значения, а не ссылки

Comment: я не должен каждый раз после обновления x и y перезаписывать в объединённый словарь dictunion = x | y

Comment: То есть создал я dictUNION = x | y и сколько бы раз я там что бы ни менял в этих x и y dictUNION должен всегда при его выводе отображать актуальное объединение x и y, а не то, которое я делал при его создании

Answer (score 0):

```
x = dict1 | dict2
print(x)
```

просто оператор объеденения |

Comment: Не работает. Просто перезаписываются значения без ссылок

Comment: dict1 = dict()
dict2 = dict()

dict1["поле"] = 1
dict2["кукуруза"] = 2

dictunion = dict1 | dict2
print(dictunion) # {'поле': 1, 'кукуруза': 2}

dict1["поле"] = 10
dict2["кукуруза"] = 20

print(dictunion) {'поле': 1, 'кукуруза': 2}

Comment: я вас не понимаю что значит ссылка в вашем понимании?

Comment: у вас всегда актуальное значение будет. Если ходите переопределить то просто x['поле']=новое значение

Comment: x я менять не собираюсь, меняются только поля dict1 и dict2. И как только я меняю любые поля dict1 или dict2, x не отображает актуальную информацию, а лишь прошлую, когда я присваивал x = dict1 | dict2. Когда говорю про ссылки, я имею в виду тот факт, что в x должна быть записана ссылка на dict1 и на dict2, а не новые объекты ключ - значение

Comment: @кириллшульжик реализовывайте свой аналог dict с требуемым поведением (через __getitem__ )

Comment: @alezhu если поняли что желает данный человек можете написать? я честно вообще не могу понять (

Comment: @Sky по сути он хочет чтобы в словаре хранились не значения, а ссылки на них. И при изменении значения по ключу в словаре  как бы менялось значение по ссылке. Таким образом, при доступе из любого использованного словаря получалось бы измененное значение, даже если меняли его через другой словарь... В общем я набросал тут код в первом приближении https://www.online-python.com/7zjnCykTtf Мне кажется этого и желают.